# How to find the source of dynamically updated aspx title

Tags: asp.net

I have seen the following content from a file named

> C:\Program Files\ClearCanvas\ClearCanvas Image Server
>   Alpha\web\Pages\WebViewer\Default.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.Web.Client.Silverlight</title>
```

As you can see, the title is dynamically replaced by **ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.Web.Client.Silverlight**. When the page is loaded, the title is as follows:

```
Studies | ClearCanvas ImageServer 3.0 Alpha
```

Is there a way that I pinpoint the source when the title is defined?

Comment: Client-side or server-side?  What do you mean by pinpoint?

Comment: It's probably internal to the silverlight app running.

Comment: @ rick, I just want to find where i can change the title.

Comment: @ Tejs, it seems that the client side is written with Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the title can be done using Page.Header.Title. You can try to do "Find all references" for Page.Header.Title, simply do a text search for 
Page.Header.Title, or set a breakpoint on the setter of that property.

Comment: I found this [assembly: AssemblyTitle("ClearCanvas.Web.Client.Silverlight")] in Web\Client\Silverlight\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 0):

Using a text editing tool like Notepad++ or using Visual Studio, do a search of the solution files on:

"Studies | ClearCanvas ImageServer 3.0 Alpha"

then, if that doesn't work, search on substrings from that title.

If you have Visual Studio, you could set a break where the title is set and examine your call stack.

Comment: I have done all those searching before I post the question here.